# How to find uiscrollview height from random string?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, height

Given the string is randomly generated, some are shorts and some are long.

```
short e.g:
description dummy text. 

long e.g:
description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text. description dummy text.
```

I want to create a uiscrollview, with fix width, lets say: 250px, and the height is depend on how many lines that the given string put into the uiscrollview. How do I calculate the height required?

Please advise :D

Comment: [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850646/dynamic-uilabel-content-inside-of-a-uiscrollview


Hope the above link helps

Comment: @iphoneFreak: It closes to what I need, but the link u gave is for uilabel. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

```
– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
```

You can find the height by this method.

Comment: Yes that should help you to dynamically resize the frame of the label depending on the text size. Based on that you can change the contentSize of the scrollview.

Comment: Addition, an alternative way, can use this: CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;

Comment: For johnie's solution to work, the textView has to be already onscreen before you change the frame.